# I can not install rails on windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

ruby -v

ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [i386-mingw32]

gem -v

2.5.1

C:\Users\JUAN>gem install rails -r --source http://rubygems.org/
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
current directory: C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/nio4r-1.2.1/ext/nio4r
```

C:/Ruby23/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20161117-6796-lcup4b.rb extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... *** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Comment: Have you tried http://railsinstaller.org/en

Comment: I can not use rails installer because right now they do not have a installer for the latest version of ruby 2.3.1.

Comment: Why do you need latest version of ruby? Just use latest available for  your OS. Rails were never meant to be used on windows. If you want to make rails apps professionally you'll have to use linux or  mac,  at  least inside a virtual machine.

Comment: The project I have to work on requires the latest version according the gem file on the git repository.
Everybody on the team must have the same version for ruby and all the gems.

Comment: Installing the last version seems to be really problematic on Windows. You should consider using a virtual machine, with VirtualBox for example and have it run on linux, Marko is right. No more problems then, you'll love it!

Comment: Also consider moving to linux. Linux Mint is great for beginners, a lot like windows but so much better. I felt so much better when I switched from windows to linux.